# kernel module function call

Tags: kernel, kernel-modules

I write a kernel module which has initialize and end function. I want one more function and want to call it from the user space process at any time i want.

Is it applicable ? If so, how ?

I am working on CentOS 5.2 and custom kernel, patched from linux 2.6.18.

EDIT:
To make clear, I want to write a function into kernel module and call this function from the regular source.c file.

Comment: To call some function in your module you would have to create a custom system call, that is the only way of directly calling into the kernel.

What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I try to use WBINVD instruction, and i want to trigger it from the userspace. This instruction is the only one that is need for our benchmark research.

Comment: What does that instruction do? Is it privileged in some way that you need to run it in the kernel? What exactly are you benchmarking, isn't there a much less invasive way of doing that?

Comment: It writes the dirty cache lines to the memory and invalidate all cpu cache. My aim is to count the cache miss/hits. Yeap, this is a privileged instruction, thats why i am trying to write a piece of kernel code.

Comment: Isn't it enough to run some random stuff before your benchmark, or make it sizeable enough that "leftover cache" effects aren't an issue?

Comment: currently i am executing some arbitrary thing ( not totally arbitrary, it tries to flush cache using a data structure ) but this method can not access to the all of the cache. WBINVD is machine instruction so it will make me sure about flushing all of the cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing a kernel module that can use the `/proc` filesystem sounds like it might work for you. [IBM developerWorks has an article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-proc/index.html) on that topic.  I worked through the code a few years ago, and it worked back then. The article is dated 2006, and seems to apply to Linux 2.6 kernels.

The problem I can foresee with using "files" in the `/proc` filesystem to get your module to do its work is that an open/read/close style API probably doesn't match what you want to do. You might have to use an open() on a `/proc` file to mean "execute WBINVD" or something unobvious like that.

Comment: I read the article but my patched kernel prompts some warnings about the vmlinux - Section mismatch. what can be the reason ?

Comment: I do not use /proc file system for the solution because of the timing problem. But I read the article and i am sure that /proc did the job unless you have a timing restriction.

Answer (score 1):

simplest thing to do is to have a character device, and write to that device, then the driver's read gets called and do the processing in the read callback of the character device in kernel.

Comment: Could you give an example which would help the user asking the question as well as people who have the same problem?

Comment: here's one: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x569.html. but can be changed to work on the latest kernels (3.5 e.t.c)